# Find character before or after of string using preg_grep() in PHP

Tags: php, preg-grep

I need to find any character before or after of a word using PHP `preg_grep()` from array. I have a array like following

`$findgroup = array("aphp", "phpb", "dephpfs", "potatoes");`

I need to find the values from the array which have 'php' word with a single or double  character before or after(either side, not both side) the word 'php'. The result should be  'aphp','phpb' word from the array.

I tried with the following code but not works.

`$result[] = preg_grep("/(.{1})php(.{1})/", $findgroup);`

Answer (score 2):

Anchor your regex and add quantifier for character before and after:

```
$findgroup = array("aphp", "phpb", "dephpfs", "potatoes", "aphpb", "php");
$result = preg_grep("/^(?:.{1,2}php|php.{1,2})$/", $findgroup);       
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => aphp
    [1] => phpb
)
```

Comment: Hi, I need another help on this. The method you showed  is return 'php' in result if the array has value 'php' in it. But I dont need it. so is there any way to return the value with a fixed length of the array value. that is the result should contain 'aphp','phpb'(fixed length 4). but result should not contain 'php'.

Comment: @SuUbha: Change the quantifiers `{0,2}` into `{1,2}`, see my edit.